# Get to customize Jquery datatables GET request parameters that will be sent to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, json-rpc

I'm using Jquery datatables and i would like when loading a page that it sends a customized GET request to the server not the default GEt request it sends. This is the JS section where it sends the request on load

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    oTable=$('#ip_data').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bScrollCollpase": true,
        "sScrollY": "200px",
        "sAjaxSource": "/url"                                                           
    });
});
```

where #ip_data is the html table id now with onload it works perfectly and this is the request headers it sends

```
http://domain.com/getdata?sEcho=1&iColumns=5&sColumns=%2C%2C%2C%2C&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=10&mDataProp_0=0&sSe arch_0=&bRegex_0=false&bSearchable_0=true&bSortable_0=true&mDataProp_1=1&sSearch_1=&bRegex_1=false&bSearchable_1=true&bSortable_1=true&mDataProp_2=2&sSearch_2=&bRegex_2=false&bSearchable_2=true&bSortable_2=true&mDataProp_3=3&sSearch_3=&bRegex_3=false&bSearchable_3=true&bSortable_3=true&mDataProp_4=4&sSearch_4=&bRegex_4=false&bSearchable_4=true&bSortable_4=true&sSearch=&bRegex=false&iSortCol_0=0&sSortDir_0=asc&iSortingCols=1&_=1402738395413
```

Now the server i'm working with is Rpc and it must get a method and params and id keys with the params part carrying the big chunk of data i.e to make the one shown above to something like this below which i have manually used and it has worked. the differences include

```
1 the addition of method=method
2 separation of method ,params and id by use of ';'
3 params={...} which is valid json
4 id=1

http://domain.com:5000/?method=datatables;params={"sEcho":"1", "iColumns":"5",    "sColumns":",,,,", "iDisplayStart":"0", "iDisplayLength":"10", "mDataProp_0":"0", "sSearch_0":"", "bRegex_0":"false", "bSearchable_0":"true", "bSortable_0":"true", "mDataProp_1":"1", "sSearch_1":"", "bRegex_1":"false", "bSearchable_1":"true", "bSortable_1":"true", "mDataProp_2":"2", "sSearch_2":"", "bRegex_2":"false", "bSearchable_2":"true", "bSortable_2":"true", "mDataProp_3":"3", "sSearch_3":"", "bRegex_3":"false", "bSearchable_3":"true", "bSortable_3":"true", "mDataProp_4":"4", "sSearch_4":"", "bRegex_4":"false", "bSearchable_4":"true", "bSortable_4":"true", "sSearch":"", "bRegex":"false", "iSortCol_0":"0", "sSortDir_0":"asc", "iSortingCols":"1" };id=1
```

I know js and jquery can do the above but i haven't been succesful with  jquery datatables since  i can't get where to make a customized request to te server to what i want. Help apreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to customize the request you need to add `fnServerData` in datatable initialization parameter with the function having customized ajax call as shown below. you can access the source, default data in `aoData`, callback function and settings, now you can add your own customized data like this,

```
aoData["MyCustomValue"] = 123;
```

or you can simply overwrite `aoData` object, its up to you
I have made a post request here.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    oTable=$('#ip_data').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bScrollCollpase": true,
        "sScrollY": "200px",
        "sAjaxSource": "/url",
        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {
            aoData["MyCustomValue"] = 123;
            oSettings.jqXHR = $.post(sSource, aoData, fnCallback, "json");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello i have followed that and done that it's perfect but the method and id parts get appended to the end of the request like ...&iSortingCols=1&method=datatables&id=1 but i wanted to separate them using a ; . Is it possible to send the params as json i had posted like domain.com/?method=method;params={};id=1 where params are the datatables variables like sEcho iColumns e.t.c?

Comment: @GideonMaina As i mentioned in the answer, i have call ajax using post request so there is no room for querystring all data will pass through formdata because request is post. now coming to you point of json. yes you can pass json like `aoData["MyJson"] = { "key" : "value"}` try it

Comment: @GideonMaina passing json in querystring is not good. better to pass it via post method

Comment: Okay I will find a way for the Rpc server to extract the method from the original request.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the following method to add `id=1` and `method=datatables`.

```
var oTable = $('#ip_data').DataTable( {
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/url",
        "data": {
            "method": "datatables",
            "id": "1",
        }
    },
});
```

In everything I've read, nothing supports construction of query strings using semi-colon instead of ampersands as separators. For that you'd have to roll your own function, see the last example here https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data

Also, passing raw json is a bit nasty. My advice would be to just let datatables automatically send the params. Datatables does this automagically if you are using the `'serverSide: true,'` option.

Comment: Thanks @ZenCodr i had tried the aoData and it worked still your method is fine !

Comment: @GideonMaina Just changed my answer completely. Don't pass around json strings using query strings. Just let datatables do that for you.

Comment: @ZenCodr Thanks! Could you provide a link to the manual section or wherever it is you found docs for this?

Comment: sure, docs for what? I put in a link to ajax-data. Everything else I just found on that same datatables.net site. The docs are amazing. Especially the manual.

Answer (score 0):

in my case . i am sending with following code

```
$('#transactions_table').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "pageLength": 3,
        "bFilter" : false,
        "serverSide": true,
        "headers": {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        "ajax":{
            data:{currency:currency_code,date_from:date_from,date_to:date_to,is_zero_fee:is_zero_fee},
            url :"http://ischool.pk",
            type: "GET"
        },"columns": [
            { "data": "transaction_id" },
            { "data": "currency" },
            { "data": "side" },
            { "data": "transaction_detail" },
            { "data": "insert_date" },
            { "data": "transaction_fee" },
            { "data": "amount" },
            { "data": "user_id" }
        ]          
    });
```